# Выделение большого контура CV2

Tags: python, opencv

Всем привет, имеется облако точек, координаты известны, выглядит так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я пытаюсь выделить контур объекта с помощью `cv2.findContours`, но получаю следующую картину
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но мне нужно как-то выделить один общий контур, чтобы получилось примерно так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу найти подходящих алгоритмов, пожалуйста, помогите

Comment: Приведите в вопросе соответствующий кусок кода...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам подойдёт совсем общий контур, то можно вот так:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('img.png')
thresh = cv.inRange(img, (128,128,128), (255,255,255))
contours, _ = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

list_of_pts = [pt[0] for ctr in contours for pt in ctr]

contour = np.array(list_of_pts).reshape((-1,1,2)).astype(np.int32)
contour = cv.convexHull(contour)

cv.drawContours( img, [contour], -1, (0,255,0), 1, cv.LINE_AA)
cv.imshow('contour', img)

cv.waitKey()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

В принципе можно даже не использовать findContours(), а сразу получить координаты точек из картинки.

```
list_of_pts = list(set(zip(*np.where(img >= 128)[1::-1])))
```

[image: -]

Comment: Cпасибо, это то, что нужно!